# XCB function to discard events from client queue (XSync(..., True) equivalent)

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xorg, xcb

In Xlib, there is [`XSync`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSync.html), which, to my understanding, will (among other effects) discard all events currently in the client's event queue if the `discard` argument is `True`.

Is there an equivalent function in XCB?

I've found `xcb_aux_sync` [mentioned](https://community.kde.org/Xcb) as such an equivalent, but I'm not sure how accurate this is and whether it applies to all events: Its [definition](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcb-util/-/blob/dbfc1c65ce343b8d0d1d8691e32d7f8e4fc0fbb3/src/xcb_aux.c#L148-152) seems to corroborate that it's "equivalent to calling `XGetInputFocus()` and throwing away the reply" as mentioned in the previous source, but [`XGetInputFocus`'s manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetinputfocus) only mentions discarding *keyboard* events, not all events in the queue across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> discard all events currently in the client's event queue

You can ask libxcb for the next queued event and just delete that. Repeat in a loop until the queue is empty.

```c
xcb_generic_event_t *event;
do {
  event = xcb_poll_for_queued_event(c);
  free(event);
} while (event != NULL);
```

I am not sure what exactly `XSync` is doing, but the above at least should answer this one part of your question.

Comment: Well, the above ignores events and errors. If you want to handle errors specially, you need to check for `event->response_type == 0`. Also, just calling `xcb_aux_sync(c)` before this loop should be equivalent to `XSync(true)`, I guess.

Comment: I was hoping there was going to be something that does it in one fell swoop like `XSync`, but coming from you I'll take this answer to mean that there almost definitely isn't :) Thanks!

Comment: Just write your own helper function. `XSync()` also has an `if` in its implementation, so you can write `my_own_sync_helper()` that also has an `if`.

Comment: One more point that just came to my mind: All of this is.... complicated in the presence of threads. `XSync()` also isn't thread-safe, but with `XLockDisplay()` one can at least lock out other threads. I never understood why people want to throw away all events and with this code (and when one uses threads), other threads could also cause threads that end up (sometimes) being ignored.